# Python child script consumes all of stdin

Tags: python, linux, bash, stdin

I discovered some strange behaviour with raw_input/readline when running python scripts within bash scripts.

In brief, when passing all of stdin at once (each entry seperated by a new line) to a parent script, the bash child scripts will *only* take the stdin that they require, while the python child scripts will consume *all* of stdin, leaving nothing for the next children. I've come up with a simple example to demonstrate what I mean:

### Parent script (parent.sh)

```
#!/bin/bash

./child.sh
./child.sh
./child.py
./child.py
```

### Bash child script (child.sh)

```
#!/bin/bash

read -a INPUT
echo "sh: got input: ${INPUT}"
```

### Python child script (child.py)

```
#!/usr/bin/python -B

import sys

INPUT = raw_input()
print "py: got input: {}".format(INPUT)
```

### Expected Result

```
./parent.sh <<< $'aa\nbb\ncc\ndd'
>> sh: got input: aa
>> sh: got input: bb
>> py: got input: cc
>> py: got input: dd
```

### Actual Result

```
./parent.sh <<< $'aa\nbb\ncc\ndd\n'
>> sh: got input: aa
>> sh: got input: bb
>> py: got input: cc
>> Traceback (most recent call last):
>>   File "./child.py", line 5, in <module>
>>     INPUT = raw_input()
>> EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

raw_input seems to purge all of the remaining lines in stdin. Using sys.stdin.readline instead of raw_input does not raise an EOFError, however the input received is an empty string, rather than the expected 'dd'.

What is happening here? How can I avoid this behaviour, such that the last child script receives the expected input?

**edit**: Just to be sure, I added a few more lines to stdin, and the result is the same:

```
./parent.sh <<< $'aa\nbb\ncc\ndd\nff\nee\n'
>> sh: got input: aa
>> sh: got input: bb
>> py: got input: cc
>> Traceback (most recent call last):
>>   File "./child.py", line 5, in <module>
>>     INPUT = raw_input()
>> EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

Comment: what happens if you have `dd\n` instead?

Comment: you would omit the dd in a `while read -a INPUT; do ...` loop as well since there is no blank new line at the end... try inserting one as @HuStmpHrrr suggested... FWIW you can fix the bash case by `while read -a INPUT || [ "$INPUT" ] do ...` I'm sure there is something similar for python, but I don't know the equivalent

Comment: Thanks, I have adjusted my answer above to avoid this confusion. Originally I had more than the needed amount of lines while testing, and I removed too much while editing my question. See edit above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an easier way of demonstrating the same issue:

```
printf "%s\n" foo bar | {
    head -n 1
    head -n 1
}
```

By all accounts, this looks like it should print two lines, but the `bar` is mysteriously missing.

This happens because reading lines is a lie. The UNIX programming model has no support for it.

Instead, what basically all tools do is to consume an entire buffer, carve out the first line, and leave the rest of the buffer for the next call. This is true for `head`, Python `raw_input()`, C `fgets()`, Java `BufferedReader.readLine()` and pretty much everything else.

Since UNIX counts the entire buffer as consumed, regardless of how much the program actually ends up using, the rest of the buffer is discarded when the program exits.

`bash`, however, works around it: it reads byte by byte until it reaches a line feed. This is very inefficient, but it allows `read` to only consume a single line from the stream, leaving the rest in place for the next process.

You can do the same thing in Python by opening a raw, unbuffered reader:

```
import sys
import os
f = os.fdopen(sys.stdin.fileno(), 'rb', 0)
line=f.readline()[:-1]
print "Python read: ", line
```

We can test this the same way:

```
printf "%s\n" foo bar | {
    python myscript
    python myscript
}
```

prints

```
Python read: foo
Python read: bar
```

Comment: Perfect. This is the way I want to do it. It looks like it is possible to achieve the same result using `f.readline()`, and then stripping the newline from the end of the string. Thanks for this explanation.

Comment: Ah, I don't know Python so I didn't know that would work. Way more convenient.

Answer (score 1):

The python interpreter will *buffer* standard input by default. You can use the `-u` option to disable this behaviour although it is less efficient.

### parent.sh

```
/bin/bash

./child.sh
./child.sh
python -u child.py
python -u child.py
```

### output

```
./parent.sh <<< $'aa\nbb\ncc\ndd'
sh: got input: aa
sh: got input: bb
py: got input: cc 
py: got input: dd
```

Comment: I wasn't aware of the -u option. Strangely, the helpstring for the -u option doesn't make any mention to stdin. I selected the solution above since it was more full-proof (and maybe more efficient), however this solution is great since it does not require any changes to the script.